# What do I do with /deep/ (and :host for that matter) when moving [S]CSS to a non-angular app

Tags: c#, css, angular, sass, razor-pages

I've searched high and low and all I get is how TO do things in Angular, not how to, well, UNDO things in the s/css files coming *from* an Angular app *to*, in my case, an `ASP.Net` app using Razor View pages. So, my question is, can someone please either tell me, or point me to [fairly specific hopefully] help that explains what to do with `/deep/` and `:host` when moving s/css *from* an Angular app *to* an ASP.Net w/Razor [View] pages app?

I swear I tried to do this on my own, but am having zero luck. (For instance, I am now *well aware* that `/deep/` has been deprecated, but I have yet to see anything that tells me what to replace it with.)

**Update:**
I get that we don't have `:host` in/on Razor Pages, but that CSS was styling SOMETHING. (*Oh if ONLY I could get that code to run*.) So, I guess what I'm [also] asking is; instead of `:host`, can I just, say, rename the `:host { display: flex; ... &.sidebar { ... } }` CSS to something like `the-host-css`, then make a `<div class="the-host-css">stuff previously styled with :host</div>` in order to get the same, or hopefully VERY similar affect?

Comment: In an ASP.NET Razor app, aren't all the styles essentially global? So you'd remove all instances of /deep/ and :host from the styles. Then you'll have to use Chrome dev tools to figure what style is no longer getting applied correctly and fix each one on a case by case basis.

Comment: @pmcilreavy not unless you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `/deep/` and `:host` were only necessary because of style isolation in Angular components.  `:host` shouldn't matter, because that styles the directive itself, you wouldn't have those elements in ASP.Net anyway.  `/deep/` can be move to the child component itself (if you have control of it).  Anything else will have to be dealt with case by case as @pmcilreavy said.